# how do i use key up function on 3 different text fields on the same page?

Tags: javascript, forms, character, keyup

I have 3 text fields and i am using the following javascript to calculate the remaining character of english and chinese characters so it changes to 160 charracters or 70 characters based on unicode. That is not the problem. The problem is they keyup function seems to work on only one of the field. it doesn't work in all three. please help ?
Thanls a lot in advance

[image]

```js
<script type="text/javascript">



    (function($){
      $.fn.smsArea = function(options){

        var
        e = this,
        cutStrLength = 0,

        s = $.extend({

            cut: true,
            maxSmsNum: 2,
            interval: 400,

            counters: {
                message: $('#smsCount'),
                character: $('#smsLength')
            },

            lengths: {
                ascii: [160, 306, 459],
                unicode: [70, 134, 201]
            }
      }, options);


        $('#day1content').keyup(function(){

            clearTimeout(this.timeout);
            this.timeout = setTimeout(function(){

                var
                smsType,
                smsLength = 0,
                smsCount = -1,
                charsLeft = 0,
                text = $('#day1content').val(),
                isUnicode = false;

                for(var charPos = 0; charPos < text.length; charPos++){
                    switch(text[charPos]){
                        case "\n": 
                        case "[":
                        case "]":
                        case "\\":
                        case "^":
                        case "{":
                        case "}":
                        case "|":
                        case "€":
                            smsLength += 2;
                        break;

                        default:
                            smsLength += 1;
                    }

                    //!isUnicode && text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€" && (isUnicode = true)
                    if(text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€")
                    isUnicode = true;
                }

                if(isUnicode)   smsType = s.lengths.unicode;
                else                smsType = s.lengths.ascii;

                for(var sCount = 0; sCount < s.maxSmsNum; sCount++){

                    cutStrLength = smsType[sCount];
                    if(smsLength <= smsType[sCount]){

                        smsCount = sCount + 1;
                        charsLeft = smsType[sCount] - smsLength;
                        break
                    }
                }

                if(s.cut) $('#day1content').val(text.substring(0, cutStrLength));
                smsCount == -1 && (smsCount = s.maxSmsNum, charsLeft = 0);

                s.counters.message.html(smsCount);
                s.counters.character.html(charsLeft);

            }, s.interval)
        }).keyup()
    }}(jQuery));


    //Start
    $(function(){
        $('#day1content').smsArea({maxSmsNum:2});
    });
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>



<script type="text/javascript>

    (function($){
      $.fn.smsArea = function(options){

        var
        e = this,
        cutStrLength = 0,

        s = $.extend({

            cut: true,
            maxSmsNum: 2,
            interval: 400,

            counters: {
                message: $('#smsCount2'),
                character: $('#smsLength2')
            },

            lengths: {
                ascii: [160, 306, 459],
                unicode: [70, 134, 201]
            }
      }, options);


        $('#day2content').keyup(function(){

            clearTimeout(this.timeout);
            this.timeout = setTimeout(function(){

                var
                smsType,
                smsLength = 0,
                smsCount2 = -1,
                charsLeft2 = 0,
                text = $('#day2content').val(),
                isUnicode = false;

                for(var charPos = 0; charPos < text.length; charPos++){
                    switch(text[charPos]){
                        case "\n": 
                        case "[":
                        case "]":
                        case "\\":
                        case "^":
                        case "{":
                        case "}":
                        case "|":
                        case "€":
                            smsLength += 2;
                        break;

                        default:
                            smsLength += 1;
                    }

                    //!isUnicode && text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€" && (isUnicode = true)
                    if(text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€")
                    isUnicode = true;
                }

                if(isUnicode)   smsType = s.lengths.unicode;
                else                smsType = s.lengths.ascii;

                for(var sCount = 0; sCount < s.maxSmsNum; sCount++){

                    cutStrLength = smsType[sCount];
                    if(smsLength <= smsType[sCount]){

                        smsCount2 = sCount + 1;
                        charsLeft2 = smsType[sCount] - smsLength;
                        break
                    }
                }

                if(s.cut) $('#day2content').val(text.substring(0, cutStrLength));
                smsCount2 == -1 && (smsCount2 = s.maxSmsNum, charsLeft2 = 0);

                s.counters.message.html(smsCount2);
                s.counters.character.html(charsLeft2);

            }, s.interval)
        }).keyup()
    }}(jQuery));


    //Start
    $(function(){
        $('#day2content').smsArea({maxSmsNum:2});
    });
    
 </script>   
    
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function($){
      $.fn.smsArea = function(options){

        var
        e = this,
        cutStrLength = 0,

        s = $.extend({

            cut: true,
            maxSmsNum: 2,
            interval: 400,

            counters: {
                message: $('#smsCount3'),
                character: $('#smsLength3')
            },

            lengths: {
                ascii: [160, 306, 459],
                unicode: [70, 134, 201]
            }
      }, options);


        $('#day3content').keyup(function(){

            clearTimeout(this.timeout);
            this.timeout = setTimeout(function(){

                var
                smsType,
                smsLength = 0,
                smsCount2 = -1,
                charsLeft2 = 0,
                text = $('#day3content').val(),
                isUnicode = false;

                for(var charPos = 0; charPos < text.length; charPos++){
                    switch(text[charPos]){
                        case "\n": 
                        case "[":
                        case "]":
                        case "\\":
                        case "^":
                        case "{":
                        case "}":
                        case "|":
                        case "€":
                            smsLength += 2;
                        break;

                        default:
                            smsLength += 1;
                    }

                    //!isUnicode && text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€" && (isUnicode = true)
                    if(text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€")
                    isUnicode = true;
                }

                if(isUnicode)   smsType = s.lengths.unicode;
                else                smsType = s.lengths.ascii;

                for(var sCount = 0; sCount < s.maxSmsNum; sCount++){

                    cutStrLength = smsType[sCount];
                    if(smsLength <= smsType[sCount]){

                        smsCount3 = sCount + 1;
                        charsLeft3 = smsType[sCount] - smsLength;
                        break
                    }
                }

                if(s.cut) $('#day3content').val(text.substring(0, cutStrLength));
                smsCount3 == -1 && (smsCount3 = s.maxSmsNum, charsLeft3 = 0);

                s.counters.message.html(smsCount3);
                s.counters.character.html(charsLeft3);

            }, s.interval)
        }).keyup()
    }}(jQuery));


    //Start
    $(function(){
        $('#day3content').smsArea({maxSmsNum:2});
    });
    
    </script>
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
<table class="table">
<tr style="background:#3C8DBC;">
<th>Day 1</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
     <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="day1content" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Content:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-3">
      <textarea name="day1content" id="day1content" width="300px" cols="60" rows="8" id="content"></textarea>
        Characters left:  (<b id="smsLength"></b>) 
         <b id="smsCount"></b> /2 SMS <br />
       </div>
     </div>
   </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
     <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="content2" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Content:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-3">
      <textarea name="day2content" id="day2content" width="300px" cols="60" rows="8" id="content"></textarea>
        Characters left:  (<b id="smsLength2"></b>) 
         <b id="smsCount2"></b> /2 SMS <br />
       </div>
     </div>
   </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
     <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="day3content" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Content:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-3">
      <textarea name="day3content" id="day3content" width="300px" cols="60" rows="8" id="content"></textarea>
        Characters left:  (<b id="smsLength3"></b>) 
         <b id="smsCount3"></b> /2 SMS <br />
       </div>
     </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know why you are recreating the plugin smsArea multiple time for each input, this is actually the problem, if you want the code to run like this you can change the names of the plugins to smsArea1,2, etc and then make each input call its own plugin, **but thats not a good practice**

a better way is to just have one plugin and feed it with any specific options you want for each input

here is a working example

```js
(function ($) {
  $.fn.smsArea = function (options) {
    var
      e = this,
      cutStrLength = 0,
      s = $.extend({
        cut: true,
        maxSmsNum: 2,
        interval: 400,
        lengths: {
          ascii: [160, 306, 459],
          unicode: [70, 134, 201]
        }
      }, options);

    $(this).keyup(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      clearTimeout(this.timeout);
      this.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        var
          smsType,
          smsLength = 0,
          smsCount = -1,
          charsLeft = 0,
          text = $this.val(),
          isUnicode = false;
        for (var charPos = 0; charPos < text.length; charPos++) {
          switch (text[charPos]) {
            case "\n":
            case "[":
            case "]":
            case "\\":
            case "^":
            case "{":
            case "}":
            case "|":
            case "€":
              smsLength += 2;
              break;

            default:
              smsLength += 1;
          }
          //!isUnicode && text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€" && (isUnicode = true)
          if (text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€")
            isUnicode = true;
        }

        if (isUnicode) smsType = s.lengths.unicode;
        else smsType = s.lengths.ascii;

        for (var sCount = 0; sCount < s.maxSmsNum; sCount++) {

          cutStrLength = smsType[sCount];
          if (smsLength <= smsType[sCount]) {
            smsCount = sCount + 1;
            charsLeft = smsType[sCount] - smsLength;
            break
          }
        }
        if (s.cut) $this.val(text.substring(0, cutStrLength));
        smsCount == -1 && (smsCount = s.maxSmsNum, charsLeft = 0);
        s.counters.message.html(smsCount);
        s.counters.character.html(charsLeft);
      }, s.interval)
    }).keyup()
  }
}(jQuery));
//Start
$(function () {
  $('#day1content').smsArea({
    maxSmsNum: 2,
    counters: {
      message: $('#smsCount'),
      character: $('#smsLength')
    }
  });
  $('#day2content').smsArea({
    maxSmsNum: 2,
    counters: {
      message: $('#smsCount2'),
      character: $('#smsLength2')
    }
  });
  $('#day3content').smsArea({
    maxSmsNum: 2,
    counters: {
      message: $('#smsCount3'),
      character: $('#smsLength3')
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thx Ahmed Farahat. I will try changing smsArea and try that again.